# Displaying Highrise Delivery Routes

Tags: routing, geocoding, indoor

I have a geocoded address table for High Rise buildings in New York. If i'm trying to map delivery routes to a number of these locations, what would be the best and most clear way to display the routes between different floors?

Comment: Check out other questions with the [indoor](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indoor) tag.

Answer (score 1):

make a stylized facade view, like the one shown at http://www.larchmontgazette.com/news/more-units-requested-for-tom-high-rise-plan/ , and draw labelled arrows inside it.

Also, see the list at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Indoor/Projects#Indoor_activities_outside_OSM and get inspired ;-)